# Using the l-apply over a function with multiple factors in R

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply, correlation

In the dataframe `df`, I construct a have a function `f` that calculates the correlation between x.sample and y.sample. Then, I am trying to run 999 randomizations that calculates the expected correlation for each randomization in `per`. I am not sure if the lapply here is written correctly and if it's actually taking in the `per` function. What is an easy way to verify this given that I'm calculating `per` and not any other function over the 4 `sp`?

```
set.seed(111)
library(truncnorm)
x <- rtruncnorm(n = 288,a = 0,b = 10,mean = 5,sd = 2)
v <- rtruncnorm(n = 288,a = 0,b = 10,mean = 5,sd = 2)
y <- ((v/x^2) - (1/x))
sp <- rep(c("A","B","C","D"), each = 72)

df <- data.frame(v,x,y,sp)

library(data.table)
setDT(df)
# function to estimate model coefficients
f <- function(x,v) {x.sample <- sample(x, length(x), replace=T)
y.sample <- (v/x.sample^2) - (1/x.sample)
per <- cor(y.sample, x.sample)}

set.seed(1234)
# 999 models for each species
result = rbindlist(
  lapply(1:999, \(i) df[,.(est = f(x,v)), sp][, i:=i])
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not super familiar with `data.table`, so the notation in the `lapply()` call looks foreign, but after playing around with it, I think it is doing what you intend.

One way to check is to code it differently and visually compare results:

```
library(dplyr)
out_list <- list()
for(i in 1:999){
  df2 <- df %>%
    group_by(sp) %>%
    mutate(est = f(x, v)) %>%
    select(sp, est) %>%
    distinct()
  out_list[[i]] <- df2
}

out_df <- bind_rows(out_list, .id = "id")

library(ggplot2)
p1 <- ggplot() + 
  geom_histogram(data = out_df, mapping = aes(x = est, color = sp, fill = sp), show.legend = FALSE) + 
  facet_wrap(~sp)
p2 <- ggplot() +
  geom_histogram(data = result, mapping = aes(x = est, color = sp, fill = sp), show.legend = FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~sp)

gridExtra::grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol = 2)
```